# R merge() rbinds instead of merging

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, rbind

I ran across a behaviour of `merge()` in R that I can't understand. It seems that it either merges or rbinds data frames depending on whether a column has one or more unique values in it.

```
a1 <- data.frame (A = c (1, 1))
a2 <- data.frame (A = c (1, 2))

# > merge (a1, a1)
#   A
# 1 1
# 2 1
# 3 1
# 4 1

# > merge (a2, a2)
#   A
# 1 1
# 2 2
```

The latter is the result that I would expect, and want, in both cases. I also tried having more than one column, as well as characters instead of numerals, and the results are the same: multiple values result in merging, one unique value results in rbinding.

Answer (score 3):

In the first case each row matches two rows so there are 2x2=4 rows in the output and in the second case each row matches one row so there are 2 rows in the output.

To match on row number use this:

```
merge(a1, a1, by = 0)
##   Row.names A.x A.y
## 1         1   1   1
## 2         2   1   1
```

or match on row number and only return the left instance:

```
library(sqldf)

sqldf("select x.* from a1 x left join a1 y on x.rowid = y.rowid")
##   A
## 1 1
## 2 1
```

or match on row number and return both instances:

```
sqldf("select x.A A1, y.A A2 from a1 x left join a1 y on x.rowid = y.rowid")
##   A1 A2
## 1  1  1
## 2  1  1
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you happen to know if I could achieve the same result without resorting to any external package?

Comment: That is what the first example shows.  If you only need a subset of columns then you can subset them after the merge.

Comment: I was thinking of a cleaner result, like the one using `sqldf`, only without using it.

Comment: You will need to fix it up afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

The behaviour is detailed in the documentation but, basically, `merge()` will, by default, want to give you a `data.frame` with columns taken from both original dfs. It is going to merge rows of the two by unique values of all common columns.

```
df1 <- data.frame(a = 1:3, b = letters[1:3])
df2 <- data.frame(a = 1:5, c = LETTERS[1:5])
df1
  a b
1 1 a
2 2 b
3 3 c
df2
  a c
1 1 A
2 2 B
3 3 C
4 4 D
5 5 E
merge(df1, df2)
  a b c
1 1 a A
2 2 b B
3 3 c C
```

What's happening in your first example is that `merge()` wants to combine the rows of your two data frames by the `A` column but because both rows in both dfs are the same, it can't figure out which row to merge with which so it creates all possible combinations.

In your second example, you don't have this problem and so merging is unambiguous. The `1` rows will get merged together as will the `2` rows.

The scenarios are more apparent when you have multiple columns in your dfs:

Case 1:

```
> df1 <- data.frame(a = c(1, 1), b = letters[1:2])
> df2 <- data.frame(a = c(1, 1), c = LETTERS[1:2])
> df1
  a b
1 1 a
2 1 b
> df2
  a c
1 1 A
2 1 B
> merge(df1, df2)
  a b c
1 1 a A
2 1 a B
3 1 b A
4 1 b B
```

Case 2:

```
> df1 <- data.frame(a = c(1, 2), b = letters[1:2])
> df2 <- data.frame(a = c(1, 2), c = LETTERS[1:2])
> df1
  a b
1 1 a
2 2 b
> df2
  a c
1 1 A
2 2 B
> merge(df1, df2)
  a b c
1 1 a A
2 2 b B
```

Comment: Thanks. I read the documentation but didn't understand it from there; I think I got it now. Do you know of a way around it? Something like merge `by="row.names()"`, but without the `Row.names` column in the result, and with the `A` column not doubled?

Comment: @KamilS. From the documentation, 2nd paragraph, last sentence: *"If there is more than one match, all possible matches contribute one row each. For the precise meaning of ‘match’, see match.*. So in the question's example first 1 in `a1` matches two  1's in `a1`, 2nd 1 matches  two 1's.

Comment: @KamilS I am not quite sure I understand what kind of result you're after. If you want the same output as the one produced by the code in the first answer (by G. Grothendieck) just wihtout the row names, you can simply do `merge(df1, df2, by = 0)[ , -1]`. This will, however, duplicate the common columns.

Comment: @MilanValášek I'd like to get the second result in G. Grothendieck's answer, essentially I'd like `merge(a1,a1)` to be identical to `a1`. Only I'd like to obtain it without using any external package.

Comment: And what should happen with potential additional columns? Say, you have two data frames like the one in my "Case 1". How should they be treated?